# ¿ Cómo usar require para utilizar un archivo de clases?

Tags: php

Intente usar `require` par utilizar las distintas funciones que tengo en el documento pero me da este error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'clase' (T_CLASS)

```
 require('clases.php');
```

y tengo mi archivo al mismo nivel que los otros archivo `php` y `html`

Comment: Cuál es el código de `clases.php` , añadir a la pregunta el código necesario para poder reproducir su código . recomiendo leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Según el error tienes un error sintáctico, posiblemente en la clase `clase`. Tal y como te ha comentado @Dev.Joel incluye por favor el codigo de `clase.php` para poder reproducir el error.

Comment: Como indican los compañeros, el error es de sintaxis, tiene toda la pinta de que en lugar de utilizar la palabra reservada **class** para declarar la clase pusiste **clase** y claro php no lo interpreta correctamente. Pero sin ver el archivo es difícil saberlo...

Comment: el código es demasiado largo para mandarlo

Answer (score 0):

Yo todas las clases las tengo cargadas de la siguiente manera:

```
include_once "../recursos/clases/Candidato.class.php";
```

No se como funcionara con requiere... De todas formas revisa tu codigo en la clase y recuerda que debes llamar a los valores adecuadamente.

Un saludo :)

Comment: El OP ha indicado que el fichero está al mismo nivel, por lo que no es necesario indicar las rutas exactas.

Comment: no funcionó no se me da el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar reuquire para mandar a llamar a tus clases de manera que que no afecte al resultado final mostrado, es decir, aunque no encuentre la clase mostrara el contenido en el navegador por ejemplo.

```
require(../modelos/crud/class.add.php);
```

Puedes tambien usar require_once para mandar a llamar las clases, pero si no las encuentra, el contenido no sera visible.

```
require_once(../modelos/crud/class.add.php);
```

O puedes usar este código para tener una auto carga de clases.

```
<?php 
/*
* Ejemplo función auto carga de clases simple.
* 
*/

function autoloader($class)
{
    include($class . ".php");
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
?>
```

Comment: intente de esa forma y me da error

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tu código, para ver qué esta dando error?